# Tag recommendation API for Stack Exchange

Tags: tags, stackexchange-api

Is there an API on Stack Exchange for recommending tags for any questions?

This is an example I have seen in myrrix. Tag Recommendation using a question as input
http://myrrix.com/example-stackoverflow-and-computation-layer/

If there is an API, how can I use it?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: i have already seen it but it seems that there is no api for  
  
input: paragraph then
output: recommended tags

Comment: Surprised there's been no activity on this, I would have thought the API was readily available. I'm also interested in the API and/or the code itself for how they do it.

Comment: I have seen that stackoverflow uses myrrix. [Here is the link to the explanation.](http://myrrix.com/example-stackoverflow-and-computation-layer/)